# Java: JSONObject isNull method doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, json, null, isnull

I need your help.  I have JSONObject like

```
 JSONObject base = {"json" : {"key1" : "somethings", "key2" : null}}
```

I've written code like this

```
JSONObject json = base.getJSONObject("json");

json.isNull("key2") // false

json.get("key2").getClass() // class.org.json.JSONObject$Null
json.opt("key2").getClass() // class.org.json.JSONObject$Null
JSONObject.NULL.getClass() // class.org.json.JSONObject$Null
json.get("key2").equals(JSONObject.NULL) // false
```

Works only :

```
 json.get("key2").equals(null) // true
```

The problem apperead when i changed some logic-structure in JSON, before isNull() worked correctly. What could have happened or changed?

Comment: I've found the reason, before i put this JSONobject to cache (other wrapper class with the field), without that it works correctly, but anyway i don't understand, why it happens in the cache

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried instantiating JSON object through constructor?:

```
JSONObject base = new JSONObject ("{\"json\" : {\"key1\" : \"somethings\", \"key2\" : null}}")
```

Comment: Actually im getting it from the API
 I've found the reason, before i put this JSONobject to cache (other wrapper class with the field), without that it works correctly, but anyway i don't understand, why it happens in the cache